# confusion regarding F-values and P-values from lmer models using "lmerTest" and 'car' packages

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a general questions about obtaining F-values and P-values from mixed models estimated in "lme4" using the "lmerTest" and "car" packages.

(1) There are several methods to obtain an ANOVA table (including F- and P-values) for a "lmer" analysis using lmerTest::anova(). Regarding the "ddf" option, it looks like most use either the "Satterthwaite" or "Kenward-Rogers" methods. I've looked into it and it looks like this is mainly done because these methods more accurately estimate the denominator degrees of freedom, and there is an option to specify the type of sum of squares for the estimation.

On the other hand, I have come across very few examples of the use of ddf="lme4". I am wondering why this may be. Is there a reason to avoid using the latter method to estimate F-values? One observation (I may be wrong) is that the F-values estimated from lmerTest::anova(ddf="lme4") are the same as stats::anova().

(2) P-values estimated using lmerTest::anova() and car::Anova() differ. Overall, they agree (i.e. they find significance or non-significance for the same variables) but the exact P-values differ, sometimes noticeably (e.g. 2-fold difference). I read that car::Anova() uses a more restrictive Wald approximation to estimate P-values, but I am unsure how this relates to the method used to estimate the P-values estimated from lmerTest::anova().

Thank you in advance for any help with my questions.

Comment: I expect the root of this issue is that `lmerTest::anova` is using Type III sums of squares, whereas `car::Anova` is using Type II. On top of that, we have the problem that p-values from a frequentist mixed model are not well defined (ie they are approximations), so it's pointless to compare them to some fixed significance level and claim "significant" or "not significant".